# Set primary color in Photoshop from hex code in clipboard

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I already have set a hotkey to "Copy color's HEX code". When pressing Ctrl+Shift+C it copies the hex code of the primary color to clipboard, so that I can paste it into another application. This is essential as a web developer. *(For those interested: Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts > Color > Copy Color's Hex Code)*

However, I would like the inverse. I have copied a color from my code or another website, such as Twitter's brand color: `1da1f2`.

I would like to press Ctrl+Shift+V to "paste" the color into my primary color, instead of having to open the color dialog, pasting it there, and pressing OK.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you're on Mac, you should check out [Color Snapper](https://colorsnapper.com/) and [SIP](sipapp.io/).

Comment: I'm using windows, so unfortunately that won't work for me. Thanks though.

Comment: A plugin could be done that does this.

Answer (score 1):

You should try Actions I think that will solve your problem. record the action of going to the color dialog and paste the value hit okay and stop recording. Assign a key on the keyboard for the action that you just recorded. and the next time you copy a color code just hit that key on the keyboard and it will play that action for you. that should fix your problem.